# How to use RegEx in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

i made a template to insert invisible whitspaces after specific characters. This template inserts and whitespace if the second substring is a "." or an "A". What i want to do now is that it inserst whitspaces before each capital letter, means i have to replace the "A" with [A-Z] like an regular expression. I tried a few things but nothing worked. How can i use regular expressions in xsl?

```
<xsl:template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
<xsl:param name="str" />
<xsl:variable name="spacechars">
            &#x9;&#xA;
            &#x2000;&#x2001;&#x2002;&#x2003;&#x2004;&#x2005;
            &#x2006;&#x2007;&#x2008;&#x2009;&#x200A;&#x200B;
        </xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="string-length($str) &gt; 0">
<xsl:variable name="c1" select="substring($str, 1, 1)" />
<xsl:variable name="c2" select="substring($str, 2, 1)" />
<xsl:value-of select="$c1" />
<xsl:if test="$c1 = '.'">
<xsl:if test="$c2 != '' and not(contains($spacechars, $c1) or
 contains($spacechars, $c2))">
<xsl:text>&#x200B;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="$c1 != ''">
<xsl:if test="$c2 = 'A' and
 not(contains($spacechars, $c1) or
 contains($spacechars, $c2))">
<xsl:text>&#x200B;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
<xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str, 2)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
<xsl:param name="str" />
<xsl:variable name="spacechars">
            &#x9;&#xA;
            &#x2000;&#x2001;&#x2002;&#x2003;&#x2004;&#x2005;
            &#x2006;&#x2007;&#x2008;&#x2009;&#x200A;&#x200B;
        </xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="string-length($str) &gt; 0">
<xsl:variable name="c1" select="substring($str, 1, 1)" />
<xsl:variable name="c2" select="substring($str, 2, 1)" />
<xsl:value-of select="$c1" />
<xsl:if test="$c1 = '.'">
<xsl:if test="$c2 != '' and not(contains($spacechars, $c1) or
 contains($spacechars, $c2))">
<xsl:text>&#x200B;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="$c1 != ''">
<xsl:if test="$c2 = 'A' and
 not(contains($spacechars, $c1) or
 contains($spacechars, $c2))">
<xsl:text>&#x200B;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
<xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str, 2)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which XSLT engine you're using. For example, it's possible to include custom c# code in your xslt transformations if it's been run using Micrsoft xslt engine.

```
<msxsl:script implements-prefix='yourprefix' language='CSharp>
    public string book(string abc, string xyz)
    {  if ((abc== abc)&&(abc== xyz)) return bar+xyz;
        else return null;
    }
</msxsl:script>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/533texsx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Iam useing the ANT FOP engine to transfrorm the documents later.

Comment: Thanks!  I spent a while looking for a good solution, and this did well for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 1.0 processors don't have support for regular expression matching or string replacement built in. There are extension that are supported by some XSLT 1.0 processors, like http://www.exslt.org/regexp/functions/replace/index.html. If you use Xalan you can check http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html which functions are supported.

In the Java world I would however suggest to move to XSLT 2.0 and for instance [Saxon 9](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.5HE) as the XSLT processor, then you can make use of the XPath and XSLT 2.0 support of the functions `matches`, `tokenize`, [`replace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) and the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction.

Comment: It looks like the extension moduls are working in my XSLT processor since exslt is just supporting a few specific processors.

Comment: My main suggestion is to use Saxon 9, perhaps someone else can tell you how to configure your environment with Ant and FOP to use Saxon 9 instead of Xalan.